# How to create a SP (service provider) for SSO (Single Sign-on) for node app?

Tags: node.js, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, service-provider, passport-saml

So I was trying to do a POC on SSO using gbraad/passport-saml-example which is not working as apparently IDp for the app stopped providing. Being a newbie in this, I have so many question, it be awesome if someone can help me answering them.
 1. Is something wrong in the code?
 2. If nothing is wrong, how do I test it? I mean, is there another IDp we can try
 3. How can we use saml2-js? Is there any working copy I can refer to?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is there https://idp.testshib.org/idp/Authn/UserPassword but as you see, the service provider is not specified, cause that link doesn't get called with a redirect binding from a trusted SAML Service Provider.

1.) not sure, I am looking for a SAMLv2 service provider solution myself (as an alternative to working Shibboleth SP I have set up) and came across this question.
2.) I did notice when looking at the repository you mentioned that it's using a different Identity Provider than the one I tested my Shibboleth Service provider on.  So, if you need a working Identity Provider, look here.  http://www.testshib.org/test.html  That is maintained by the people who maintain Shibboleth I believe. 
3.) I am going to dive into the saml2-js with what I know about Service Providers and see if I can get it going.

My main objective for not using the Shibboleth modules for Apache or IIS is, I don't know how to get hold of the attributes without scraping.  Hoping the express solution will be easier to understand and stand up quickly, while meeting other important requirements.